# Tengo dos action para una sola ruta pero no se como armar la URL

Tags: zend

Tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar, tengo una ruta con hijo, como esto:

```
'apps' => array(
    'type'          => 'Segment',
    'options'       => array(
        'route'       => '/apps[/[:action[/:id]]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ),
        'defaults'    => array(
            'controller' => 'Apps\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'index'
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes'  => array(
        'ximages' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => '/ximages[/[:action[/:id_ximage]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults'    => array(
                    'controller' => 'Apps\Controller\xImages',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Ahora en el archivo `.phtml` quiero acceder a la ruta `http://miserver/apps/view/1/ximages/images/1` y lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
echo $this->url('apps/ximages', array(
        'action'    => 'view',
        'id'        => 1,
        'id_ximage' => 2
    ));
```

Pero ese código solo me imprime a la ruta `http://miserver/apps/view/1/ximages/index/1` y no se como se le puede pasar el nombre del `action` de la ruta hija.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoría, el array que vas pasar a `$this->url(...)` no debería tener dos `key` iguales, creo que podría causar errores al montar la url, y aún más tratándose de la parte que resuelve `controller` y `action`, que no debería producir ambigüedades.

La ruta que estás montando debería tener todos estos parámetros:

```
echo $this->url('apps/ximages', array(
    'action'    => 'view', // <-- parent
    'id'        => 1, 
    'action'    => 'images', // <-- child
    'id_ximage' => 2
));
```

Cosa que no debe ser posible por lo antes comentado. Al no poder resolver el segundo action, toma el que tiene por defecto el `route` que es el `index`.

Algo que se me ocurre sería pasar los parámetros de la ruta padre a la ruta hija mediante la modificación del `route`.

```
'child_routes' => array(
    'ximages' => array(
        'type'    => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'       => '/:parent_action/:parent_id/ximages[/[:action[/:id_ximage]]]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'parent_action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                'parent_id'     => '[0-9]+',
                'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'id_ximage'     => '[0-9]*',
            ),
            'defaults'    => array(
                'controller' => 'Apps\Controller\xImages',
                'action'     => 'index'
            )
        ),
    ),
)
```

Llamándolo así:

```
echo $this->url('apps/ximages', array(
    'parent_action' => 'view',
    'parent_id'     => 1,
    'action'        => 'images',
    'id_ximage'     => 2
));
```

De nuevo, en teoría, al tener los parámetros `action` e `id` del `route` padre configurado como que puede o no estar presente en la `url`, debería resolver con la ruta que estás buscando.

***No lo he probado, pero a raíz de como resuelve las rutas zf2 debería ser una alternativa a tu pregunta.***

De no ser así, y al montar la url te solicita que faltan los parámetros de la ruta padre, se debería cambiar el planteamiento de la construcción de las rutas y montar la clásica `'route' => ':controller/:action/:id1/:id2/...'`

Depende de como se planteen las rutas pueden ser un elemento más con el que trabajar, o generarte verdaderos dolores de cabeza.

---

**EDITO**

---

He montado un módulo de prueba y el problema es lo que venía diciendo desde el inicio. Dos key iguales en el `route` genera problemas, ya que resuelve primero el `action` del `route` `apps` y deja por defecto el `action` del `route` `apps/ximages`.

Con el planteamiento que realizo, a pesar de ser parámetros opcionales, hay que pasar forzosamente los parámetros `action` e `id` si son variables y no se pasa un valor por defecto.

Así que de querer mantener esta estrategia de `routes`, con parámetros variables, (sobre todo el `action`), tendrías que buscar la forma de inyectar los parámetros del `route` `apps` y después montar el `ViewHelper` `$this->url(...)`. Solución que va a resultar más tediosa de construir y mantener, y desconozco si funcionaría correctamente.

Particularmente lo solucionaría poniendo el `route` paralelo a `apps` en vez de como un hijo.

```
'apps'    => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'       => '/apps[/[:action[/:id[/]]]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'     => '[0-9]*',
        ),
        'defaults'    => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),

'ximages' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'       => '/apps/:parent_action/:parent_id/ximages[/[:action[/:id_ximage[/]]]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'parent_action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
            'parent_id'     => '[0-9]+',
            'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id_ximage'     => '[0-9]*',
        ),
        'defaults'    => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Other',
            'action'     => 'index'
        )
    ),
),
```

Y montar el `ViewHelper`

```
$this->url('ximages', array(
    'parent_action' => 'view',
    'parent_id'     => 2,
    'action'        => 'images',
    'id_ximage'     => 9,
));
```

Comment: No, lamentablemente así tampoco funciona. Pensaba hacer una sistema con controladores que sean todos hijos. Me refiero algo como:

/user/view/1/city/view/1/street/edit/1

Y que yo pueda usar el controlador "StreetController" para editar la id_street = 1 pero creo que se puede, solo que el $this->url no puede construir una URL de esa forma.

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos que error te da? lo que comentaba que solicitaba los parámetros del `route` padre?

Comment: Para construir una url así `/user/view/1/city/view/1/street/edit/1` lo único que hay que plantear es como se va a alimentar el `ViewHelper` de los parámetros necesarios para que construya la url que necesitas. En ocasiones es necesario plantear `routes` que sean paralelos en vez de anidados por que la construcción los posteriores `routes` hijos pueden generar este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Por alguna razón me sale el error: `Missing parameter "parent_action"`

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos sospecho de donde puede ser el error, estoy montando un módulo para probarlo. Ahora te comento.

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos he modificado la respuesta añadiendo datos sobre lo comentado

Comment: O.o maravilloso, funciono. Entiendo que es mejor dejarlo paralelos en vez de que sean hijos, porque como me dices es más fácil crear la ruta (Y) genial, un millón de gracias !!!!!

Comment: Me alegro de que funcionase.